# PHP wrong redirect

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When Im on my localhost SQL, it works. But now when I uploaded it to my clients SQL, it doesent. When I log in, it supposed to redirect to edit.php, after it has checked from database whether the name and password are correct or not, but it stays blank. Im out of ideas what to do, because it does work on my localhost sql.

Where I login, login form, (login.php)

```
<?php

include_once("logikinnitus.php");

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['logged']))
{

    header('Refresh: 2; URL=http://www.heakohv.ee/fava/admin/edit.php');
    echo "olete juba sisse logitud!";

  }else {

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $name = $_POST["user"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];

    $object = new User();
    $object -> login($name, $pass);
}

?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="login.php">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user"/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">
</form>

<?php 

}

  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Where I check if the password and user are correct (logikinnitus.php)

```
<?php

include_once("connection.php");


Class User {

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }

    public function login($name, $pass){

        if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass)){

            $st = $this -> db -> prepare("select * from users where name=? and pass=?");
            $st -> bindParam(1, $name);
            $st -> bindParam(2, $pass);
            $st -> execute();

            if($st -> rowCount() == 1){

                session_start();
                $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
                echo "Olete edukalt sisse logitud";
                header('URL=http://www.heakohv.ee/fava/admin/edit.php');
                exit();

            }
            else{

                echo "Parool või kasutajanimi on vale";

            }

        }
        else{

            echo "Palun täida kõik väljad!";

        }

    }

}

?>
```

connect php, (connection.php)

```
<?php

class Connection{

    public function dbConnect(){
        return new PDO("mysql:host=host; dbname=name", "pass", "");
    }
}

?>
```

Warning I get when error report turned on.

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/home/la02/16840949/tmp/sess_46e83b3c6e65b60a68dd14f525bd92a5, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/la02/16840949/admin/login.php on line 6

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/la02/16840949/admin/connection.php:3) in /home/la02/16840949/admin/login.php on line 6

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/la02/16840949/admin/connection.php:3) in /home/la02/16840949/admin/login.php on line 6

Warning: Unknown: open(/home/la02/16840949/tmp/sess_46e83b3c6e65b60a68dd14f525bd92a5, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/home/la02/16840949/tmp) in Unknown on line 0

If I add session.save_path"folder" it doesnt bring even my login form up anymore... I see only blank page from the beginning, even no errors –

Any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Could it be because you are `echo`ing before redirecting to edit.php?

Comment: You can turn php error reporting on to help debug - `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1); ...`

Comment: The 1st & Last 2 Warnings are the ones to look at. Check to make sure your tmp folder `/home/la02/16840949/tmp` exists and has write privileges. If that is not the correct location, you should update the tmp folder location in your php.ini file `session.save_path`

Comment: If I add session.save_path"folder" it doesnt bring even my login form up anymore... I see only blank page from the beginning, even no errors –

Answer (score 3):

There is no header `URL`. Use `Location: http://domain.com` for redirecting.

Also you can't output anything before sending headers, so remove all `echo`s before it.

In your first code you have to add `die` after sending header. Without it, script will be executed to the end (maybe not a problem here, but you should always stop script while redirecting).

Comment: he is not using a `URL` header he is using a `Refresh` header that uses a `URL` option, which is valid, though technically depreciated

Comment: @PatrickEvans Look at the 2nd block of code, inside the `login()` function - `header('URL=http://www...)`

Comment: @Elon That is certainly another issue with the code, but not the reason for all the initial warnings.  However, once he dealt with the warnings, he would have to deal with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are telling you what the problem is--- the session files can not be read or written, as they appear to be writing them to your *nix user home directory.

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/home/la02/16840949/tmp/sess_46e83b3c6e65b60a68dd14f525bd92a5,
>   O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in
>   /home/la02/16840949/admin/login.php on line 6

Is your code doing a [session_save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) call?  If not you need to check the value of the session.save_path variable in the applicable php.ini file.  You can create a simple script in your document root with:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

If you have any question about the runtime value of these settings.

This could also be a permissions issue depending on how your php/web server is configured.  Usually the session files would be written to the /tmp directory, but in your case they are not.  If you actually intended to write the session file to the place where it is being written, if that directory does not exist, and/or the user that is running the php process does not have permissions to read/write those files, then you're going to get the errors you're getting.

Comment: Also, see the issue Elon pointed out... your header there is wrong, as he shows.  You want to make it consistent-- Use the location header in both places, or better yet, move that to a method to make your code DRY.

Comment: If I add session.save_path"folder" it doesnt bring even my login form up anymore... I see only blank page from the beginning, even no errors